# Testing connectivity and port availability using SSH instead of Telnet

Tags: ssh, telnet, port, connectivity

Assume that you have a pair of UNIX/Linux machines. You want to check if both machines can connect to each other via an arbitrary port, say, TCP 111.

Log into the shell of Machine 1 (10.0.0.1). If Telnet is installed on it, you can check the connectivity with 10.0.0.2 by using the command

```
$ telnet 10.0.0.2 111
```

But some UNIX/Linux systems do not have Telnet by default. SSH is more popular thus it may be preferred, especially when you don't want to install exra applications on your machine.

[image: An illustration]

***Question.*** Is there any way to test the same with ease, by using the ssh command instead of the telnet command?

(Please answer the question. *"You can install Telnet or use Microsoft Windows"* doesn't help. TCP 111 is just an example.)

Comment: You can use netcat or just bash with /dev/tcp/ instead of telnet. And probably many other tools. This sounds like a totally artificial question.

Comment: `ssh` is the wrong tool (arguably as is `telnet`)

Comment: No ``nc``, ``telnet``, Microsoft Windows, or any non-standard tools please. As far as I know ``/dev/tcp`` opens a TCP connection to the associated socket..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can be certain that ssh is installed, but not nc. In light of that, the question could make sense.

Use the -p option. For example port open:

```
$ ssh -p 111 192.168.1.16
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Port closed:

```
$ ssh -p 112 192.168.1.16
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.16 port 112: Connection refused
```

Comment: I am pretty certain that ``nc`` is not as common as ``ssh``. For example, CentOS 7 doesn't come with ``nc`` by default.

Comment: This tip also helps those on Windows, as telnet was disabled starting with Vista, but ssh (openssh) has been bundled since later versions of Windows 10 and Server 2019.